# I removed a user from the Authy app. Can I recover the same or get the details about that user's past activity logs?

Tags: authy

I removed a user from the Authy app. Can I recover the same or get the details about that user's past activity logs?

need to check if that removed peroson loggen in if yes then logs

I tried to read docs by Authy however I just found how to remove a person. restore backup password etc. what exactly i am looking for is before removing a device i forgot to check if or when authy was logged in through same devise.